# Adding an image with a specific aspect ratio to a ScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a compound component to a scroll view but keeping the aspect ratio of the component the same. I have the top and bottom of the compound component constrained to parent and have constrained the aspect ratio. The issue that I have is that the scroll view does not know what the width of the compound component is so it chops off what ever is not on the screen. is there a way to make the Scroll View not chop off the leading and trailing edges of the compound component while preserving the aspect ratio of the image?  [image: Screenshot of the autolayout]

Comment: Try creating a constraint that sets the width of the compound component equal to the scrollView's width and then change that to a <= constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution to my problem. What I did was change the constraints so that the leading and trailing edges were constrained instead of the top and bottom. I then played around with the aspect ratio until I got everything to fit properly. I also set the content mode to scale to fill.